# Does the current_session object know too much about the User object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop

I have two classes:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :articles
  ...
end
```

And:

```
class CurrentSession
  def initialize(...)
    ...
  end

  def managing
    User.where(...).first
  end
end
```

The `User` class is an object which inherits from Rails AR. Keep in mind, User has the association `has_many :articles`. You will also notice that `current_session` exposes the User object via the `managing` method. This is done using composition.

```
current_session = CurrentSession.new(...)
current_session.managing.articles if current_session.managing.present?
```

Is it right that `current_session` now has access to the `Article` object via the `managing` method?

Does `current_session` know too much? Did I just leak the contents of the `Article` object into `current_session`? Is that so bad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `User` is an ActiveRecord model, and you expose that model through a method on another class, then yes, you will expose *all* of the model, including it's relations and the methods on those relations.

I would ask this question: How much do you need to expose? What's the purpose of returning the full user in the `Session#managing` method? Given the name of the class, maybe all you need is to keep track of the user's ID? Then just return that. Problem solved. If you do need the full user, I don't see how (or why) you would prevent access to it's relations.